# Parse XML with JRuby (Hpricot?) with tags like <foo.bar>

Tags: xml, ruby, jruby, hpricot

I'm trying to consume some legacy XML with elements like this in JRuby:

```
<x-doc attr="value">
  <nested>
    <with.dot>content</with.dot >
  </nested>
</x-doc>
```

I've been working with Hpricot, but Hpricot's HTML-oriented shortcuts are working against me: `doc.search("//with.dot")` seems to be looking for `<with class="dot" />`

(I ran into this problem with JQuery too, a few years ago.)

Can I do this with Hpricot, or do I need to use a different library?

Comment: Someone posted (and then deleted) an answer suggesting I just use native Java tools for this. I could do that, but I was hoping to stick with Hpricot for its simpler API. I could also drop JRuby and use pure Java, but I'm experimenting with ways to manipulate XML with something more light-weight and easy to change with only a text editor. (No recompile/deploy, as my target system has a JRE but no JDK.)

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug with Hpricot. In this situation I'd be tempted to do a search and replace on "with.dot" before hand so I could then use Hpricot. You could return it to it's previous state after you've finished doing what you want with Hpricot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).  It's said to be "A Faster, Better HTML and XML Parser for Ruby (than Hpricot)".

Comment: Thanks -- it's great to see that doc.search("//with.dot") works properly in Nokogiri.  Sadly, it doesn't work on my target platform, which doesn't have any -dev packages (nor even a compiler) installed.

Comment: It now seems as if Nokogiri is working on Jruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811864/possible-to-load-nokogiri-in-jruby-without-installing-nokogiri-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448512/how-to-use-nokogiri-from-jruby-on-windows