# How to use nokogiri from Jruby on Windows?

Tags: windows, jruby, nokogiri, libxml2

I'm getting the following error when trying to use Nokogiri with Jruby on Windows 7

```
D:\code\h4>jruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'nokogiri'"
D:/jruby-1.3.1/bin/../lib/ruby/1.8/ffi/library.rb:18:in `ffi_lib': Could not ope
n any of [xml2, xslt, exslt] (LoadError)
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.3.3-java/lib/nokog
iri/ffi/libxml.rb:5
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.3.3-java/lib/nokog
iri/ffi/libxml.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/bin/../lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.3.3-java/lib/nokog
iri.rb:10
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.3.3-java/lib/nokog
iri.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/jruby-1.3.1/bin/../lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:36:in `require'
        from -e:1
```

Seems to be a problem with native extensions (libxml2) incompatibility of Jruby, however I've found a [workaround here](http://maodan520.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E0C8D36B1650926A!237.entry), but couldn't find libexslt.so and am not sure where to put it. Does anyone have a successful experience of using jruby+windows+nokogiri+libexslt? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround you found is for a UNIX system; the .so file is a loadable module, similar to a DLL in Windows. And you can't softlink in Windows (the `ln -s` command), so that doesn't apply in your situation.

Nonetheless, you do have the same problem in that nokogiri can't find your **libxml2, libxslt, & libexslt libraries**. Since I don't use JRuby or nokogiri, I'm really not sure how it'll work, but my best guess is this:

Most likely, you need Windows binaries (DLLs) of [libxml2](http://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/libxml2-2.7.3.win32.zip) and [libxslt](http://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/libxslt-1.1.24.win32.zip) at a minimum; other related Windows binaries may be needed and are available at the [same place](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html#binaries). You'll want the DLLs installed somewhere in your path, or better yet in the same directory as your JRuby executable (looks like "D:/jruby-1.3.1/bin"). (If that doesn't work, perhaps a Java-native form of the libraries like libxmlj might work, but I doubt it--you probably need ones native to Windows.)

I expect that will get you on your way to working.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you need the xml2 / libxslt dlls in your path.

However, I have found it necessary to update to jruby-1.4.0RC2 (for some FFI improvements I believe).

Also, need to update to the latest nokogiri 1.3.3 & manually apply the following commit:

http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/commit/0555c69e70083a6368b563f18da2c8d5416515cc

OR install nokogiri from github trunk.

I hope this is helpful.

Useful background links:

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3781
- http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/closed/#issue/137
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4052
- http://kenai.com/jira/browse/RUBY_FFI-46

Answer (score 1):

There is now a pure Java version that can run on Windows as well.

```
gem install nokogiri --pre
```

Found here

```
https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/pure-java-nokogiri-for-jruby
```