# Downloading from wallpaperswide.com by Vikas' script

Tags: ruby

I am a total noob but I was trying to download wallpapers from wallpaperswide.com
using Vikas' Ruby script found at the following page :
http://vikas-reddy.blogspot.in/search/label/download

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and have downloaded and installed the following before
running the script :

rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p125.exe

wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe

nokogiri from [How to use nokogiri from Jruby on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448512/how-to-use-nokogiri-from-jruby-on-windows)

I did not install "open-uri" though as I did not know how to do this.

I copied the script and saved it as a txt file and changed the extension to .rb and 
ran the file but the following error message appears in the command prompt window :
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Please provide detailed help. Thanks.

The script is as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
#  Vikas Reddy
#
#  A little script to download ALL the wallpapers of a given
#  resolution from http://www.wallpaperswide.com/
#
#  Requirements
#  ============
#  Ruby Version: 1.9.2
#  Gems: nokogiri, open-uri
#  Other programs: wget
#
#
#  Available Resolutions
#  =====================
#
#  Wide
#  
#  * 16:10 960x600
#  * 16:10 1152x720
#  * 16:10 1280x800
#  * 16:10 1440x900
#  * 16:10 1680x1050
#  * 16:10 1920x1200
#  * 16:10 2560x1600
#  * 16:10 3840x2400
#  * 16:10 5120x3200
#  * 5:3 800x480
#  * 5:3 1280x768
#  
#  HD
#  
#  * 16:9 960x540
#  * 16:9 1024x576
#  * 16:9 1280x720
#  * 16:9 1366x768
#  * 16:9 1600x900
#  * 16:9 1920x1080
#  * 16:9 2048x1152
#  * 16:9 2400x1350
#  * 16:9 2560x1440
#  * 16:9 3554x1999
#  * 16:9 3840x2160
#  
#  Standard
#  
#  * 4:3 800x600
#  * 4:3 1024x768
#  * 4:3 1152x864
#  * 4:3 1280x960
#  * 4:3 1400x1050
#  * 4:3 1440x1080
#  * 4:3 1600x1200
#  * 4:3 1680x1260
#  * 4:3 1920x1440
#  * 4:3 2048x1536
#  * 4:3 2560x1920
#  * 4:3 2800x2100
#  * 4:3 3200x2400
#  * 4:3 4096x3072
#  * 5:4 1280x1024
#  * 5:4 2560x2048
#  * 5:4 3750x3000
#  
#  Mobile Ratio
#  
#  * VGA 240x320
#  * VGA 480x640
#  * VGA 320x240
#  * VGA 640x480
#  * WVGA 240x400
#  * WVGA 480x800
#  * WVGA 400x240
#  * WVGA 800x480
#  * HVGA 320x480
#  * HVGA 480x320
#  * HVGA 640x960
#  * HVGA 960x640
#  * iPad 1024x768
#  * iPad 768x1024
#  * HD 16:9 480x272
#  * HD 16:9 272x480
#  * Phone 176x220
#  * Phone 220x176
#  
#  Dual
#  
#  * 4:3 1600x600
#  * 4:3 2048x768
#  * 4:3 2304x864
#  * 4:3 2560x960
#  * 4:3 2800x1050
#  * 4:3 2880x1080
#  * 4:3 3200x1200
#  * 4:3 3360x1260
#  * 4:3 3840x1440
#  * 4:3 4096x1536
#  * 4:3 5120x1920
#  * 4:3 5600x2100
#  * 4:3 6400x2400
#  * 4:3 8192x3072
#  * 5:4 2560x1024
#  * 5:4 5120x2048
#  * 5:4 7500x3000
#  * 5:4 10240x4096
#  * 16:10 1920x600
#  * 16:10 2304x720
#  * 16:10 2560x800
#  * 16:10 2880x900
#  * 16:10 3360x1050
#  * 16:10 3840x1200
#  * 16:10 5120x1600
#  * 16:10 7680x2400
#  * 16:10 10240x3200
#  * 5:3 1600x480
#  * 5:3 2560x768
#  * 16:9 1920x540
#  * 16:9 2048x576
#  * 16:9 2560x720
#  * 16:9 3200x900
#  * 16:9 3840x1080
#  * 16:9 4096x1152
#  * 16:9 4800x1350
#  * 16:9 5120x1440
#  * 16:9 7108x2000
#  * 16:9 7680x2160
#  * 3:2 2880x960
#  * 3:2 4000x1333
#  * 3:2 2304x768
#  
#  Other
#  
#  * 3:2 1152x768
#  * 3:2 1440x960
#  * 3:2 2000x1333


require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

Resolution = "1600x900"
Base_URL   = "http://wallpaperswide.com/#{Resolution}-wallpapers-r/page/"
Output_Directory = "/home/vikas/Wallpapers/"

# Create the Output_Directory if needed
`mkdir -p "#{Output_Directory}"`

(1..2492).each do |page_num|

# Go page by page
url = Base_URL + page_num.to_s

# Parse html
f = open(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)

# Loop over image-boxes
doc.css("div.thumb").each do |wallp|

# Extract wallpaper subpage url
wallp.css("div[onclick]").attr("onclick").value =~ /prevframe_show\('(.*)'\)/
subpage_url = $1
subpage_url =~ %r|http://wallpaperswide\.com/[^/]+/([\w\d]+)\.html|

# Generate url of the required wallpaper
wallp_url = %|http://wallpaperswide.com/download/#{$1}-#{Resolution}.jpg|

# Download... with a user-agent parameter just in case...
# use '--limit-rate=100k' to limit download speed
`wget -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"`
end
end
```

Comment: I think you need open-uri since it's required

require 'open-uri'

Comment: it's shelling out to linux commands for some strange reason so unless you're running it from cygwin it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the two gems that are required. open-uri is part of the standard library so you don't need to install it but nokogiri isn't. Install it as follows

```
gem install nokogiri
```

The shelling to create te map and to do the download with wget would better be replaced by ruby code, should not be difficult if you search for some examples but they should work in windows. You will need to make sure wget is in the path or give the path with the command eg

```
`"c:/program files/wget/wget.exe" -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"`
```

EDIT:
First try this

```
Output_Directory = "c:\temp"
Resolution = "1600x900" 
wallp_url = %|http://wallpaperswide.com/download/#{$1}-#{Resolution}.jpg| 
command = %|"C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/wget.exe" -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"|
puts command

#=> "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/wget.exe" -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "c:  emp" "http://wallpaperswide.com/download/-1600x900.jpg"
```

You shouldn't get an error. Mind the forward slashes.
Then you run the command that is put in your console by pasting it at the command-line.
If you get an error, there's something wrong with yourpaths or the firefox parameters. 
Only if the wget works (you have the image in the c:\temp map) your script could work.
In your scipt you can then run the command like this:

```
`command`
```

If still an error in the script, publish the error here.

Comment: I have replaced the line `wget -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"`with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget,exe" -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"` but the same error appears. PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment out the 'wget' line in the code and put in its place a puts statement like this:

```
# `wget -c -U "Firefox/4.5.6" -P "#{Output_Directory}" "#{wallp_url}"`
puts "#{wallp_url}"
```

This would output the urls generated. That should ideally spit out ten urls at a time continuously. If that is happening, the problem could surely be because of your wget installation in Windows or its usage.

The only platform-dependent code in this piece of code is this.
I've written the detailed procedure to be followed in Windows systems in my latest blog post, at http://vikas-reddy.blogspot.in/2012/06/wallpaperswide-download-script-in.html