# XPath select node with periods

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, syntax, nodes

I have an XML document where some of the nodes have a `.` in their name:

```
<com.site.blah>
   <id>asdkjasd</id>
   <com.site.testing>
       <name>test</name>
    </com.site.testing>
</com.site.blah>
```

If I try `@doc.search("/*/id").first.xpath`, it returns `/com.site.blah/id`, but if I then do: `@doc.search("/com.site.blah/id").first.inspect` it returns `nil`.

I want to be able to make an XPath query to select the name under `com.site.testing`, but it keeps rejecting my queries.

Any ideas?

(I am using hpricot if it makes a difference)

Comment: Have you tried escaping those dots in a query?

Comment: @Nikita - Yes, I have tried `com\.site\.blah` and that does not work

Comment: Why didn't you try `com.site.blah`? (http://codepad.org/ecVVUPCu)

Comment: @Tomalak - I tried both.

Comment: try to really escape the dot (`&#46;`)

Comment: Related: [Parse XML with JRuby (Hpricot?) with tags like `<foo.bar>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396511)

Comment: @webdestroya: Sure there are no namespaces involved?

Comment: @mykhal - Nope, that didnt work either

Comment: @Tomalak - Nope, the XML document is basically exactly what I posted. There is no `<?xml...` tag either and their are no namespaces

Comment: works as expected with nokogiri..

Comment: THis is actually *not* an XPath question but an xpathengines question. In standard XPath using names with dots is OK, if you have problems then your XPath engine is not compliant as per W3C spec.

Comment: @mykhal - Indeed it does. I am switching to Nokogiri

Comment: @webdestroya: It should be no problem. In MSXSL, I can get "asdkjasd" with `/com.site.blah/id`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your XPath library is broken. An XPath name test is a QName (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-NameTest), which, after following the rabbit hole of EBNF, includes periods (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar). Report the error to the developers.

As a workaround, neither of the escape mechanisms mentioned in the comments are part of XPath, but you can try using a predicate to check the element name, like so:

```
/*[name(.) = 'com.site.blah']/id
```